# Upload PDF to OneDrive Microsoft Graph Rest API

Tags: javascript, pdf, sharepoint, graph

I would like to use JavaScript to upload a PDF file to my SharePoint Office 365 site. I have been able to 
- Authenticate and received Token
- Use example to create a plain text file

I would like to upload a PDF file onto SharePoint. I have tried converting the file to binary and to base64 but the resultant file appears to be a text file.

```
var xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/drive/root:/test10.pdf:/content"
xhr.open("PUT",url,false);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "bearer" + " " + TOKEN);
//xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/octet-stream");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/pdf");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Encoding","base64");
xhr.send(filecontent);
```

Is anyone able to help?

Thank you
Terry

Comment: Your question and example is clear, but you should also include any errors, warnings, etc.  Its not really clear what the problem is.  If you don't see an errors, but are getting erroneous results, perhaps a link to the documentation will help too.  Also, did you try jQuery.ajax?  Might help to abstract the XHR.

Comment: I don't get any errors as the binary string/base64 was saved as a text file when i was expecting a PDF. The PDF would not open as a PDF. Viewing the content in notepad it is the string I submitted.

Comment: Question is how do I send a none plain text file to SharePoint using the Graph rest api?

Comment: I don't know anything about the graph api, but i think for pdf you may need to use binary to maintain its encoding.  there's got to be something similar in the documentation.  see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15664712/binary-lines-in-multipart-form-data-file-upload good luck.

Comment: I have tried changing he content type to octet stream too but for some reason the content is still a string and a plain text file is created just with a pdf extension. Looks like It is not recognising the input as base64 or binary

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. When reading the file in the content was set to text. I had to change the type to binary.

Bs.Type = 1